# How can I convert a WMF image to PNG or JPG on Windows using Perl?

Tags: perl, module, png, jpeg, wmf

By any chance is anyone aware of a Perl module that will allow a WMF image to be converted over to the PNG or JPEG format? I searched CPAN, but did not come across anything.

Due to installation limitations, must be a Perl module and work on Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Image::Magick](http://search.cpan.org/dist/PerlMagick/Magick.pm) is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

I hear good things about [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php), though I haven't used it personally. Looks like it will do [that conversion](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php)